# Referring to Blender 3.1. Why is there now a pie menu in the outliner by default

Tags: interface, navigation

Why is there now a pie menu in the outliner. Now I cannot select an item in the outliner unless I hold the control key.

Answer (score 2):

A pie menu has been added to the outliner for 3.1 but has to be initiated with the grave/tilde key (between the ESC and TAB keys on a UK/US keyboard).
[image]

[image]

Suggest you look in <kbd>Edit</kbd> > <kbd>Preferences</kbd> > <kbd>Keymap</kbd> to see how it's been set.
[image]